# Tell me please with php - function - return

Tags: php, strlen

I wrote for myself a function that checks the number of characters - I cannot figure out how to properly use it

Are these options correct?

```
function checkStrlen($check,$min,$max) {
 return strlen($check) < $min || strlen($check) > $max ? true : false;
 }
```

or better wrap in ()

```
function checkStrlen($check,$min,$max) {
 return (strlen($check) < $min || strlen($check) > $max) ? true : false;
 }
```

Here I do not like this option - using (if)

```
 function checkStrlen($check,$min,$max) {
    if (strlen($check) < $min || strlen($check) > $max) { return false; }
    return true;
 }
```

Damn completely confused - All options are working but I would like to know how to do it correctly.

I use it like this

```
 if(checkStrlen($login, 3, 30)) {
 echo '<div class="error">Login must consist of at least 3 characters and no 
 more than 30!</div>';
  }
```

I do not understand (how to use 'strlen' in 'return' )

return  ? true : false;
 return () ? true : false;

About 'mb_strlen' I know - I just gave for example

By the way, sorry for the mistakes I'm Russian - used google translate!

Thank you all - the best option is: 
 return strlen (lalala) <3 || strlen (lalala)> 30;

Comment: All your code snippets are basically equivalent. They are all equally correct.

Comment: Your condition is already evaluated as a boolean, so there is no need to use the ternary operator or if to return true or false : `return strlen($check) < $min || strlen($check) > $max ;` is enough

Comment: The most readable option is often the correct one. `?true:false` is a pointless no-op for boolean expressions. To make this question answerable, you should document what that function was supposed to do. The first two have (probably) the opposite results of what you wanted.

Comment: The best option -  return strlen ($ check) <$ min || strlen ($ check)> $ max; -  Without use -? true: false; - I didn't know that it was possible!   Without you, I would never have guessed, Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you're using it like that, the function is clearly misnamed. What it really does is `checkNotStrlen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just omit the `?:` operator.

```
function checkStrlen($check, $min, $max) {
    return strlen($check) < $min || strlen($check) > $max;
}
```

---

## Conversion to boolean

You can sometimes use conversion to boolean. This is **not** the case when you need it because the `||` operator always returns boolean.

### `!!` notation

If you want to convert something to boolean in PHP or JavaScript (both of them use the same syntax for this), you can use prefix pseudo-operator `!!`. It is not real operator but it negates the negated value. (Makes `true` from `true` and `false` from `false`.)

```
// PHP
$foo = 1;
$bar = !!$foo;
/* $bar is TRUE */

// JS
var foo = 1;
var bar = !!foo;
/* bar is true */
```

### Casting

Casts are used more often to convert anything to boolean in PHP. See [PHP documentation](http://php.net/boolean#language.types.boolean.casting).

```
// PHP
$foo = 1;
$bar = (bool)$foo;
/* $bar is TRUE */
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the one which is wrapped in () because it makes it easy to read and understand the code. Anytime in future if you have the need to look at this code, you'll not get confused about what these lines are for.

```
function checkStrlen($check,$min,$max) {
 return (strlen($check) < $min || strlen($check) > $max) ? 
true : false;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I like it more, but I didn't know if I did it right.

Comment: Why is the `?:` operator used here?

Comment: Because I did not know that without him it was possible - I just saw somewhere that they did it something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the best way.
Happy Coding

```
function checkStrlen($check,$min,$max) {
 return (strlen($check) < $min || strlen($check) > $max) ? true : false;
 }
```